# why i can't create the Dependency propety in another Class in some Class Library

Tags: wpf

> i am trying to create one dependency property in a class called
> "FocusBehaviour" that is in Class library.. I have added the
> namespaces like below.. But it showing error in line  1) return
> (bool)control.GetValue(FocusFirstProperty);
>
> error: System.windows.Controls.Control Doesn't have a method
> 'GetValue" that accepts the First argument of type
> System.windows.Controls.Control. 2) The same error is coming from
> SetValue() also...below that... 3) Control control = dpObj as Control;
> error:Cann't convert System.DependencyObject To
> System.windows.Controls.Control
>
> I Also Added the WindowsBase Reference..

```
  using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MyOrgBI
{
    public static class FocusBehavior:DependencyObject
    {

        public static readonly DependencyProperty FocusFirstProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("FocusFirst", 
                                            typeof(bool),
                                            typeof(Control),
                                            new PropertyMetadata(OnFocusFirstPropertyChanged));

    public static bool GetFocusFirst(Control control)
    {
        return (bool)control.GetValue(FocusFirstProperty);
    }
    public static void SetFocusFirst(Control control, bool value)
    {
        control.SetValue(FocusFirstProperty, value);
    }
    static void OnFocusFirstPropertyChanged(DependencyObject dpObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Control control = dpObj as Control;
        if (control == null || !(args.NewValue is bool))
        {
            return;
        }
        if ((bool)args.NewValue)
        {
            control.Loaded += (sender, e) => control.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.First));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Previously I created a dependency property in a WpfApplication project. It worked fine but when I create one in another class library it shows this error.

Why these errors Coming ? And how should I write this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the `WindowsBase` Assembly. [DependencyObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.aspx) is located there.

Comment: even though i added the "WindowsBase" from AddReference option in References, it didn't close that error...

Answer (score 2):

Derive your class from `DependencyObject`

```
public static class FocusBehavior : DependencyObject
{
    ...
}
```